# Shell script file, checks if text file is empty or not

Tags: shell, text-files

I want to check if `.todo.txt` is empty or not.
If is is empty, I want to add the echo in the file, and if it already has content, I want to do something else.

I tried:

```
hasData()
{
    echo "Hello"
}

isEmpty()
{
    echo -e "$n\t$comment\t$dueD/$dueM/$dueY " >> .todo.txt   
}

if [ -s $file ] ; then
    hasData()
else
    isEmpty()
fi
```

When I run above code, I get the following:

```
./todo.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./todo.sh: line 25: `   else'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when i run my code i get the following ./todo.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token else' ./todo.sh: line 25: else'

You must use parentheses to *define* a shell function, but they have no part in calling one.  A shell function is invoked just like any other command:

```
if [ -s $file ] ; then
    hasData
else
    isEmpty
fi
```

If your functions took arguments, then you would list them after the function name -- again, just like for any other command.